# Mock SqlBulkCopy in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Which Interface or abstract class should I use to mock SqlBulkCopy object in c#?
I am trying to BCP table from Oracle to SQL Server.

Please let me know if there is an alternate solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no suitable interface. Create a wrapper class.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the closest is passing a TVP to the SQL Server stored proc using a ADO.Net SqlCommand.

For that, you need to load first all records into DataTable, then pass the DataTable to the SqlCommand.

Check this link http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/

Another option is calling the BULK INSERT directly from C#  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx